# take a string and turn it into a date

Tags: string, vb.net, date, format

I am needing to take a string like 20230131 and turn it into 2023/01/31 then eventually reformat that into  DD/MM/YR format. I am reading this from a txt file through stream reader and having to write it to a new file in different format using stream writer.

Using Visual Basic

```
Dim Start As String
Dim FileData()
FileData = myReader.ReadFiles()
Start = FileData(2)
myWriter.WriteLine("A004 " & Start)
```

I have tried start = Format(FileData(2), "####/##/##")
But it keeps writing only #'s instead of the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

Since the string is a date, it would be easier to convert it to a DateTime type. Here is how you can parse the string into a DateTime:

```vb
Dim NewDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Start, "yyyyMMdd")
```

From there, you can format the DateTime however you want. The .NET framework provides an overloaded method on the DateTime type called `ToString()`. The method allows you to pass in a string for the format (and culture-specific options if desired). Here is an example of that:

```vb
NewDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Here is a link to the method's documentation on Microsoft Learn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0

## Update:

The `DateTime` type, as the name suggests, stores both the date and time. Because of that, you do not need to store the individual date and time portions separately. The `ToString()` function can represent both date and time values together. The code below is updated to show this.

If `StartDate` does not have a corresponding time portion, then the below code should work. If it does have a time portion, like FileData(3), you would have to add it just like the `FinishTime` below.

```
Dim FileData()
FileData = myReader.ReadFiles()
Dim StartDate As String = FileData(2)
Dim FinishDate As String = FileData(4)
Dim FinishTime As String = FileData(5)

Dim NewStartDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
Dim NewFinishDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(FinishDate & FinishTime, "yyyMMddhhmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

myWriter.WriteLine("A004 " & NewStartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & " " & NewFinishDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Parse exact is most definitely the right solution here. Date.tryparse.may also suffice, however I'd you know for a fact that your fats are in a certain format,.just get right to it and use `parseExact.`

Comment: when I use Dim NewDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Start, "yyyyMMdd") it tells me that overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ParseExact' accepts this number of arguments

Comment: Sorry, it also needs a culture option specified. I see you figured that out in your other code. I have updated my answer with some changes that will hopefully work for you.